# Pure virtual method returning an object?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do this pure virtual method:

```
   virtual MonLaser& getLaser() = 0;
```

But I get all sorts of errors:

```
Error 6 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
Error 5 error C2253: 'MonMartien::getLaser' :
  pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
Error 13 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error 7 error C2433: 'MonMartien::MonLaser' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
```

I need to be doing a pure virtual method, or else I can't access my `Laser`. Do You have any idea?

Comment: Allow me a stupid question, is `MonLaser` the type of the object? If so, try returning a `pointer` instead of a `reference`.

Comment: try including a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Yes, MonLaser is an object of MonMartien. I'll try that, but why would it work?

Comment: Hold on...I've made a mistake. Say, where is `MonLaser` defined? I mean the class/struct, whatever?

Comment: It's defined in MartienJiggle, a sub class of MonMartien.

Comment: And then I have MonMartien pointer tab pointing on several MartienJiggle and MartienPlotton

Comment: Wait, you're having a superclass return a subclass object? While that is...uncommon, try a forward declaration. Put `class MonLaser` above your definition of `MonMartien`. Don't forget to `include` the header file of `MonLaser` (in `MartienJiggle`) in the .c file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After learning, that the method is returning a custom type from within the class `MonMartien` I have a different theory now.

You see, this error message suggests, that the type is unknown at the time of compilation. Make sure that you have your declaration of `MonLaser` BEFORE the declaration of `MonMartien`. If you have both in the same header make sure you put the declaration of `MonLaser` above the declaration of `MonMartien`. If it's in a separate file, be sure to include the header file.

Also, make sure that the declaration is NOT inside the class, since then the type would be invisible and thereby inaccessible to anyone outside of the class.

In the essence it all boils down to: Where is `MonLaser` defined?

Comment: @Tomek Agreed, I just noticed a mistake in my thought process.

Comment: No no! MonLaser is in MartienJiggle, a sub class of MonMartien.

Comment: @Maxwell Try putting the declaration of `MonLaser` into a global scope. Maybe even a separate file, which is included by both `MartienJiggle` and `MonMartien`.